I am confused about potential energy and work done by a force

Potential energy is the energy contained in a body due to its position. But I don't understand it because when object falls, PE= mgh and work done by gravity, is - mgh. So what is the difference other than the sign? Why do we need to consider a new energy called PE when we can already just find the work done by the force? i am even more confused because energy is work done right?

Does that mean only objects in rest have potential energy? Or do objects in motion also contain potential energy? For example, I move a book from point A to B. Does it have PE only in A and B?

When should we consider and not consider the PE of the body?

What is the difference between work energy theorem (WOT) and conservation of mechanical energy (COME)? Why is WOT applicable for everything and COME applicable only for conservative forces? And for both these theorems, shoul we consider internal or external forces?

What is the derivation for COME



Please narrow this down to a single question.

Object vs system

To your bullet point 2.

An object does not contain potential energy due to its position. Rather, a system contains potential energy due to its arrangement. If the Earth suddenly dissapeared, the energy associated with the object-and-Earth system would also disappear. Clearly, this is not energy stored within just the object. The full form of the gravitational potential energy also shows that two different masses are involved:
$$U=G\frac{Mm}{r}.$$
The shorter formula $mgh$ that you typically use is just a short-hand formula for this where the $g$ already factors in e.g. Earth's mass.
Such potential energy is always associated with a system, so not only when your object is at point A or B, but also anywhere in-between.
Potential energy vs work

To your bullet point 1.

There are different types of energy. Potential energy is "stored" energy, kinetic energy is "motion" energy, and there are many more. But work is not a type of energy. It is just the mechanical transfer of energy. So, when potential energy is release and converted into, say, kinetic energy (i.e. if you push a book down from a shelf), then then we say that work was done because energy was transferred.
Work represents the transition, the transfer, the conversion of energy between types. And if all the potential energy is transferred at once, then sure, the work done equals the magnitude of the once stored potential energy.
Zero level
You might often see potential energy being set to zero at some specific arrangement. For example, you might often hear gravitational potential energy as being zero on the floor. Then, when a book is placed on a shelf, gravitational potential energy is stored in the book-and-Earth system. When the book falls and lands on the floor, then zero energy is stored.
But that is wrong!
Because what if you dig a whole in the floor and let the book fall into the hole? It will fall down and thus release even more energy (even more work is done). How could extra energy be released if zero energy was stored?
The explanation is that it is not the true value of potential energy that is useful. It is only ever the difference in potential energy between two different arrangements (between the book being on the shelf and on the floor i.e.) It is only this difference which is transferred as work when released. Since only the difference matters, then it doesn't matter where you place the zero level!

You can place the zero level on the floor, and calculate that $10\,\mathrm J$ are stored while the book is on the shelf, then $10\,\mathrm J$ will be released as work when it falls to the floor.
Or you can place the zero level on the shelf, in which case you would calculate a potential energy value of $-10\,\mathrm J$ on the floor, and the difference will still be $10\,\mathrm J$.
Or you can place the zero level at the bottom of the hole you dig into the floor. Then maybe you calculate a value of $30\,\mathrm J$ for the shelf and of $20\,\mathrm J$ for the floor, and the difference is still $10\,\mathrm J$.

Of that reason, the zero level is often conveniently placed to be the ground or the floor or the like. But it truely doesn't matter. The full formula for gravitational potential energy $U$ that I showed above has the zero level chosen as a point infinitely far away - because that is the only way to choose an objective point that does not depend on circumstances.
The short-hand formula you use $mgh$ is in fact not a formula for potential energy but a formula for a potential energy difference, $\Delta U=mgh$. In this formula you have implicitely chosen the zero level to be where you measure the height $h$ from.
Work-energy Theorem vs Law of Energy Conservation

To your bullet point 4.

The law of energy conservation is fundamental and always applies. You can write it for instance like this:
$$\sum E_1=\sum E_2,$$
since any energy at one moment must always be the same in any other moment. The energy might be rearranged, converted, transformed, moved, sure. But the total must remain the same.
Now, if you take some energy out of or add energy to a system in some way - maybe by heating it up or so - then you this law turns out to not be true for your system. We say that your system is not isolated when this can happen (when energy can leave/enter the system). Then you must adjust your energy conservation equation to something like this:
$$\sum E_1+Q+W=\sum E_2,$$
where $Q$ is heat and $W$ work added to the system, the two types of energy transfer that are possible. Note that you might have different signs on $Q$ and $W$ in different textbooks due to different definitions of whether they are positive/negative when added/removed.
In a purely mechanical case there is no $Q$ involved. Also, the energies will only of mechanical types, like elastic potential energies, gravitational potential energies, kinetic energies etc. With these mentioned, your energy conservation formula now looks like this:
$$\sum E_1+Q+W=\sum E_2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad U_{e_1}+U_{g_1}+K_1+Q+W=U_{e_2}+U_{g_2}+K_2.$$
And this is typically also known as the work-energy theorem. So, this is just a special-case of the more general energy conservation law. You cannot say that work is only considered in the work-energy theorem and not in the energy conservation law; that is only true if you "forget" to take into account what is added/removed when you system is not isolated.
Notice, that you are welcome to add in many more types of energy in the energy conservation equation. Like electrical potential energy, magnetic potential energy, chemical energies, other internal energies, or what about the gravitational potential energies associated with Jupyter etc. But if those energies do not change between the two moments in time (or if they are insignificantly small), then they obviously just cancel out. So, to answer the last part of your bullet point 4, you are welcome to consider all those other types of energies as well, but there is no point if they do not change. Only those that change are relevant - regardless of whether they are internal or external.
Experimental law vs derived theorem
The work-energy theorem is derived from the energy conservation law. That is why it is called a theorem (generally, the term theorem is used for statements that proven on the basis of other already known stuff).
The energy conservation law itself, though, is not derived from anything else. In fact, it cannot be proven. It is an experimental result.
Scientists have experimented for millenia and never, ever found any counterexample where energy conservation does not hold true. Thus, we have come to believe that it always will be true - just as surely as we believe that gravity will still work tomorrow. We cannot prove it, but we believe in it so strongly that we consider it a fundamental law of nature.
There is some to say about this, though, in regards to more abstract depths of physics. But that is for another level, I belive, so let's just stop here.

Thank you so much for taking your time to write this explanation! Your explanation really helped me understand a lot of things and I am genuinely grateful to you

@android You are so very welcome! Glad to be of help.


We can always define work done by a force, but we can't always define potential energy. Friction is a notable example. Friction can do work (slowing down is also work), but we could never define a potential because friction depends on velocity. We can define a potential whenever the work done on something does not depend on the path it takes, only on the initial and final positions. Gravity fits this. Friction does not. Potentials are usally very convenient to work with.


Energy is just work right

I would say work is a transfer of energy. If you compare energy to money then the energy of an object would be their bank account and work would be a transaction.

objects in motion also have potential energy. In fact, potential energy does not depend on velocity. Potential energy only depends on position in space. For example, gravitation potential only depends on $z$.

A potential is very nice to work with, so if it is possible to define one you use it.




Why is WOT applicable for everything and COME applicable only for
conservative forces?

It's in the name: conservation of mechanical energy. Anytime energy is converted to something else than mechanical energy (think heat, radiation, sound, chemical energy, etc.) COME does not apply. Work-energy simply always applies. Why? You should look into a proof for this theorem.

I think this should be a separate question. You can also find this on google probably.

